# Xamarin iOS Tap event going through a top most view?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uibutton, xamarin

I have a UIView (lets call it the Top View) that I add on-top of an existing view (lets call it the Bottom View) by simply calling the Add(UIView) method of the ViewController.

The Bottom View has a UITextField and UIButton and the Top View has a UIButton in the same exact spot as the Bottom View. The issues I am experiencing is that whenever I tap the UIButton on the TopView, the Tap event seems to go "through" the view and occur on the UIButton on the Bottom View. The Top View UIButton doesn't even seem to respond to touch events.

I am even able to tap "through" the Top View, in the spot of the UITextField in the Bottom View and cause the keyboard to come up.

Anyone who has experienced issues like this, any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "disabling" UI interaction on the bottom view? There's a property on UIView (and it's subclasses) to enable / disable UI interactions.

Comment: If the `Frame` of your top view is too small, the button will be displayed but it won't capture taps. To check if this is the issue set `ClipsToBounds = true` on your top view. If the button disappears, you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try as per wolfgang, but also check that your top view has the UI interaction set. The event chain will find your back view if it doesn't find your top view first.